# How do I link tf_conversions to a RViz panel?

Tags: ros, tf-conversions, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am designing a Qt panel that is integrated into RViz.
At some point this Qt panel needs to convert an `Eigen::Affine3d` to a `geometry_msg::Pose`.

I fail to understand why `tf_conversions` is not linked to my package:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(custom_rviz_plugin)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
             geometry_msgs
             rviz
             tf
             tf_conversions)

catkin_package()

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui REQUIRED)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})

add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)

qt4_wrap_cpp(MOC_FILES
  src/my_panel.h
)

set(SOURCE_FILES
  src/my_panel.cpp 
  ${MOC_FILES}
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(FILES 
  plugin_description.xml
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>custom_rviz_plugin</name>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <description>RViz plugin.</description>
  <author>Victor Lamoine - Institut Maupertuis</author>
  <maintainer email="victor.lamoine@gmail.com">Victor Lamoine</maintainer>
  <license>BSD</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>rviz</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf_conversions</build_depend>

  <exec_depend>rviz</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>geometry_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>tf</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>tf_conversions</exec_depend>
  
  <export>
      <rviz plugin="${prefix}/plugin_description.xml"/>
  </export>
</package>
```

The whole package is available [here](https://github.com/VictorLamoine/rviz_panel_tf_conversions).

When adding the panel in RViz (using `test.launch` in the package) the constructor crashes because of a missing symbol:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/rviz/rviz: symbol lookup error: /home/victor/MEGAsync/catkin_workspace/devel/lib//libcustom_rviz_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2tf14poseEigenToMsgERKN5Eigen9TransformIdLi3ELi2ELi0EEERN13geometry_msgs5Pose_ISaIvEEE
```

Which is confirmed because tf_conversions is not linked to the Qt panel library:

```
$ ldd /home/victor/MEGAsync/catkin_workspace/devel/lib//libcustom_rviz_plugin.so | grep tf
    libtf.so => /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libtf.so (0x00007fd1b1af1000)
    libtf2_ros.so => /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libtf2_ros.so (0x00007fd1adfe2000)
    libtf2.so => /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libtf2.so (0x00007fd1addb2000)
```

How do I link `tf_conversions` to a Qt / RViz panel?

**EDIT 1:**
Even linking manually does not work:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fPIC -L/opt/ros/indigo/lib/ -ltf_conversions")
```

The library is still not linked to `tf_conversions`.

**EDIT 2:**
My work-around at the moment is to re-declare the function:

```
namespace tf {

template<typename T>
void poseEigenToMsgImpl(const T &e, geometry_msgs::Pose &m)
{
  m.position.x = e.translation()[0];
  m.position.y = e.translation()[1];
  m.position.z = e.translation()[2];
  Eigen::Quaterniond q = (Eigen::Quaterniond)e.linear();
  m.orientation.x = q.x();
  m.orientation.y = q.y();
  m.orientation.z = q.z();
  m.orientation.w = q.w();
  if (m.orientation.w < 0) {
    m.orientation.x *= -1;
    m.orientation.y *= -1;
    m.orientation.z *= -1;
    m.orientation.w *= -1;
  }
}

void poseEigenToMsg(const Eigen::Affine3d &e, geometry_msgs::Pose &m)
{
  poseEigenToMsgImpl(e, m);
}

void poseEigenToMsg(const Eigen::Isometry3d &e, geometry_msgs::Pose &m)
{
  poseEigenToMsgImpl(e, m);
}

} // tf
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228549/how-do-i-link-tf_conversions-to-a-rviz-panel?/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2016-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-03-10**:
The source and header files look good as far as I can see. I'm not sure what qt4_wrap_cpp() is in your cmakelists.txt file though. Will it work if you put the header file explicitly in SOURCE_FILES?

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2016-03-10**:
qt4_wrap_cpp() is called to use the Qt MOC (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html). No it doesn't work either. Manually linking does not work too (see my edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The symbol you're missing is in the eigen_conversions library (libeigen_conversions.so). You should probably add a catkin dependency on eigen_conversions to link against it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2016-03-12**:
Meh.. that's right! When using `eigen_conversions`, I should link against `eigen_conversions`... :)